# Has anyone used a lightning + Micro USB to USB-C cable

Tags: iphone, usb, lightning

I just purchased an USB-C to Lightning cable, but when it came I realized that it has also a micro USB right in the Lightning connector. My fear is that the short circuits will damage the iPhone if I insert it the wrong way. The iPhone itself has pins only on one side. Are this cables safe? Should I remind myself every time that I need to insert it in a certain way?

[image: cable]

Comment: It doesn't look as if that cable could be in any way [MFi-certified](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204566).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally never seen a cable like this. i have seen Micro USB to Lightning adapters like [this.](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD820ZM/A/lightning-to-micro-usb-adapter)

Personally I would be more careful than usual and just not force the cable if it doesn't go in as then you could be inserting the Micro USB to not damage the phone. After all if this was sold legally this must have been verified.

So in conclusion just be careful and don't force it in.

Also as mentioned by the OP be careful with the two pins.

After taking a closer look the adapter doesn’t seem certified so I recommend throwing it away.

Comment: Thanks, just a warning for others, i did insert it in a phone and those 2 little metal pins from the back used by the micro usb, scrapped some plastic from the inside of the phone lighning. I'll have to either cut them, either throw the cable away, don't really have a usage for it as a micro usb.